# About bash : cd: too many arguments in my vmware kali linux

Tags: bash, kali-linux, cd-command

Having problems with this, it is not working.

[image: too many arguments...]

Comment: This probably shouldn't be migrated out, but as an FYI, Kali isn't on topic at Ask Ubuntu.  :P   (Also, if your host machine has wifi, but you don't have a USB wifi adapter passed through to the VM, this is a ***VERY*** common occurrence of seeing this kind of output - you can't give the host wifi adapter to the VM)

Answer (score 6):

This tells your shell to look out for all files whose names match the pattern, take those names, and pass them to `cd`.

`cd` takes 1 and only 1 argument. This means that it will receive an invalid number of arguments whenever there is not 1 and only 1 file which matches the pattern.

You're probably looking for autocomplete. Just hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. If it doesn't autocomplete, there either are no options or more than one. In the latter case, hit the key a second time to get a list of proposals, type a few more characters until the name is unambiguous, and hit it again to complete the name.